# Finding the exact value of $b$ when given the argument in $z=(b+i)^2$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

[image]

In the answer to the above question, there are two methods. My method was that I expanded $(b+i)^2$ out and I do $\arctan \frac{2b}{b^2+1}$ and then solve quadratic equation.

However, my friend did it in this way: 
[image]

I don't understand why he can ignore the squared bit of $(b+i)$ and then take the complementary angle - $30^\circ$?

Please advise.

Thanks in advance and sorry for any wrong tags or title naming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its simple $arg$ shows similar properties  to logs so its $arg(b+i)+arg(b+i)=30+30$ thus $arg(b+i)=30$ and then normal procedure

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

What your friend has used is basically this property:

$$arg(z_1z_2)=arg(z_1)+arg(z_2)+2k\pi$$

where $z_1=z_2$ and hence $k=0$.

Do you get now what your friend has done?

Comment: Yes Thank you very much @SchrodingersCat, so it means 2 arg(z1)=60.

Comment: @CCC You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Notice:

- $$(a+bi)^2=(a+bi)(a+bi)=(a^2-b^2)+(2ab)i$$
- $$\arg(x+iy)=\begin{cases}
  \arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\text{if}\space x>0\\
  \arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)+\pi\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\text{if}\space x<0\space\text{and}\space y\ge0\\
  \arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)-\pi
  \space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\text{if}\space x<0\space\text{and}\space y<0\end{cases}$$

  ---

So, given:

- $$z=(b+i)^2\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\text{with}\space\space b\in\mathbb{R^+}$$
- $$\arg((b+i)^2)=\frac{\pi}{3}\space\space\space\space\space\space\text{with}\space\space b\in\mathbb{R^+}$$

  ---

So, solving the problem:

$$\arctan\left(\frac{2\cdot b\cdot1}{b^2-1^2}\right)=\frac{\pi}{3}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\arctan\left(\frac{2b}{b^2-1}\right)=\frac{\pi}{3}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{2b}{b^2-1}=\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{2b}{b^2-1}=\sqrt{3}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{b}{b^2-1}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{1}{b-\frac{1}{b}}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$b-\frac{1}{b}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{b^2-1}{b}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\sqrt{3}(b^2-1)=2b\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\sqrt{3}b^2-2b-\sqrt{3}=0\Longleftrightarrow$$

Solving $b$ with the quadratic formula gives:

$$b=\sqrt{3}\space\space\space\vee\space\space\space b=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$$

So, $b$ has to be positive:

$$z=\left(\sqrt{3}+i\right)^2$$